# Slow boot after clean install of Natty

Tags: 11.04, boot, upstart

The time have risen from 20-25 sec in Meerkat to 35 sec in Natty. I do not know if it is `ureadahead` but made a bugreport of it in launchpad. I tried Fedora shortly before installing Natty. They use `systemd` instead of `upstart` and didn't have this slow boot.

In a dmesg this jump shows up:

```
[    3.087606] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   15.292831] <30>udev[308]: starting version 167
```

How could it be that booting got so much worse? I also have a "black screen" much longer before Plymouth splash starts in Natty then in Meerkat. Could it be the famous kernel regression?

Comment: +1 I have the same problem, and I also saw it in other people's posted dmesg output.  What on earth is it doing between seconds 3 and 20?: [    3.106155] EXT3-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
[   20.726183] Adding 10239996k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:10239996k 
[   20.784551] udev[301]: starting version 167

Comment: Intresting.. as you are using EXT3, i EXT4 and i have seen others with BTRFS. It doesn't seem to be the file system.

Comment: I have a similar dmesg log: `[    3.413050] EXT3-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode` and `[   17.810635] Adding 1998844k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1998844k`. Did you came any further? Do you have the link to the bug report?

Comment: This page from ubuntuforums.org fixed my similar problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11388915&postcount=18

Answer (score 2):

I set ACPI=off in grub... it worked :)

It boots in about 30 second (before that 2-3 minutes).

Comment: Have alreaady tried that.. i think that solution is for another regression than mine. Mine is just off ~20 sec.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

1. Install **cryptsetup** package. It doesn't harm your system, but fixes long "black screen" before Plymouth
2. Remove and then install back **ureadahead** package. After that perform reboot. Check that /var/lib/ureadahead/pack file is created ~1-2 minutes after reboot.
3. Reboot with timer now :)

Comment: Tried it but didn't solve my problem. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

In /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules comment this rule:

```
# ATA/ATAPI devices (SPC-3 or later) using the "scsi" subsystem
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", \ SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{type}=="5", ATTRS{scsi_level}"[6-9]*", \ IMPORT{program}="ata_id --export $tempnode"
```

Then run as root:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

*Via http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3116527.0*

Comment: Although i have a crappy DVDRW it didn't work for me.. Thanks for the suggestion. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a strangely slow boot on my freshly installed 11.04 (around a minute on a brand new computer), Then I changed the SATA-port on my DVD-drive from a 6Gb/s port to a 3Gb/s port. This change improved my boot time to 20 seconds. I'm not sure why this worked but it's certainly worth trying if your DVD drive is connected to a 6Gb/s SATA port.

Comment: My motherboard is old so that is most probably not it for me. But thanks for the proposal. I bet someone else might have this problem and get helped by it.