# Very slow boot due to mounting filesytem

Tags: 11.04, boot, filesystem

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 over an older version of Ubuntu, and am dual-booting with Windows 7. Most things seem to be working well (i.e. wifi, sound, etc.) but boot time is problematically long. After choosing 11.04 from grub 1.99, I get the purple screen for several minutes before the Ubuntu log-in finally appears.

According to dmesg log, the delay seems to be related to mounting the file system:

```
...
[   28.989223] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

[  305.166041] Adding 3178492k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:3178492k 

[  305.169951] udev[265]: starting version 167

[  305.268165] lp: driver loaded but no devices found

[  305.403739] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,user_xattr

[  305.843685] type=1400 audit(1305950932.592:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=449 comm="apparmor_parser"

[  305.849067] type=1400 audit(1305950932.600:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=449 comm="apparmor_parser"

[  305.856958] type=1400 audit(1305950932.608:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=449 comm="apparmor_parser"

[  305.859426] Detected Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device - installing RFKill handler

[  306.041961] toshiba_bluetooth: Re-enabling Toshiba Bluetooth
...
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am rather new at this and would really like to move to linux. Thanks, and sorry in advance if the answer is really obvious!!

---

Ok, here's part of the log from rebooting right after removing ureadahead/pack

```
...
[    2.792630] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    2.797648] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   11.894554] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  120.445148] Adding 3178492k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:3178492k 
[  161.949893] udev[282]: starting version 167
[  162.023334] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,user_xattr
[  162.894059] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[  163.022000] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[  163.102500] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (064e:c211)
[  163.125699] input: USB 2.0 Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/input/input4
[  163.125954] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  163.125962] USB Video Class driver (v1.0.0)
[  163.254969] Detected Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device - installing RFKill handler
[  163.255877] toshiba_bluetooth: Re-enabling Toshiba Bluetooth
[  163.731246] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  164.164064] usb 3-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
[  164.169805] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[  164.664232] i915 0000:00:02.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[  164.664247] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  164.711758] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[  164.711774] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 1 (10.10.2010).
[  164.711781] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[  164.755680] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  164.755691] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  164.755701] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  164.755710] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  164.755718] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  164.755727] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  164.755736] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  164.784201] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[  164.784589] [drm] initialized overlay support
[  164.901359] Synaptics Touchpad, model: 1, fw: 7.2, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xd04733/0xa40000/0xa0000
[  165.008626] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[  165.070964] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.15
[  165.071056] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[  165.071062] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  165.071070] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  165.074598] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x37
[  165.074677] fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[  165.074683] drm: registered panic notifier
[  165.092856] acpi device:01: registered as cooling_device2
[  165.094858] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6
[  165.095264] ACPI: Video Device [IGD0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[  165.097822] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[  165.165873] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
[  165.168253] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[  165.325992] type=1400 audit(1306246511.880:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=453 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  165.327099] type=1400 audit(1306246511.880:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=453 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  165.327828] type=1400 audit(1306246511.880:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=453 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  165.329429] type=1400 audit(1306246511.884:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=490 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  165.330528] type=1400 audit(1306246511.884:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=490 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  165.331261] type=1400 audit(1306246511.884:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=490 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  165.347775] ath9k 0000:07:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[  165.347804] ath9k 0000:07:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  165.398272] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x65
[  165.398278] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[  165.398286] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[  165.398290] ath: Regpair used: 0x65
[  165.398298] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398306] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398312] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398319] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398324] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398331] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398337] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398344] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398350] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398357] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398362] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398369] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398375] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398382] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398388] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398395] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398400] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398407] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398413] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398420] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398426] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398433] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398438] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2467 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398445] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398451] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2472 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  165.398458] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  165.398464] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz as custom regd has no rule that fits a 20 MHz wide channel
[  165.400589] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain 
[  165.600141] fixme: max PWM is zero.
[  166.305256] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'ath9k_rate_control'
[  166.307102] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0::radio
[  166.307197] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0::assoc
[  166.307274] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0::tx
[  166.307352] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0::rx
[  166.307379] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9285 Rev:2 mem=0xf8420000, irq=17
[  167.351088] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
[  167.351198] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[  167.351258] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  168.340294] hda_codec: ALC272: BIOS auto-probing.
[  168.352207] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
[  168.352613] input: HDA Intel Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[  170.962880] type=1400 audit(1306246517.516:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=727 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  170.963690] type=1400 audit(1306246517.516:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=727 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  170.964540] type=1400 audit(1306246517.520:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=727 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  171.008505] type=1400 audit(1306246517.564:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/share/gdm/guest-session/Xsession" pid=726 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  171.198493] type=1400 audit(1306246517.752:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=734 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  171.199837] type=1400 audit(1306246517.752:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=734 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  171.239142] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[  171.262460] type=1400 audit(1306246517.816:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=744 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  171.306533] type=1400 audit(1306246517.860:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=728 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  171.316601] type=1400 audit(1306246517.872:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=728 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  171.323405] type=1400 audit(1306246517.876:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" pid=728 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  174.283804] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  174.301000] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: link down
[  174.301514] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  174.325236] Bluetooth: L2CAP ver 2.15
[  174.325245] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  174.540563] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  174.540573] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  174.924470] Bluetooth: SCO (Voice Link) ver 0.6
[  174.924479] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  177.636159] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,commit=600
[  188.127378] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,commit=600
```

And then here's after I rebooted it a second time after doing that (as you can see, the boot time just went right back up):

```
...
[    3.427105] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    3.432917] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   17.957660] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  388.568753] Adding 3178492k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:3178492k 
[  388.659406] udev[269]: starting version 167
[  388.864853] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,user_xattr
[  388.917659] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[  389.899832] type=1400 audit(1306247595.366:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=415 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  389.922486] type=1400 audit(1306247595.390:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=415 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  389.924183] type=1400 audit(1306247595.394:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=415 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  391.045604] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[  391.147662] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: link down
[  391.153944] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  391.209670] Detected Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device - installing RFKill handler
[  391.229006] toshiba_bluetooth: Re-enabling Toshiba Bluetooth
[  391.609521] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  392.244187] usb 3-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
[  392.552440] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[  393.252233] type=1400 audit(1306247598.721:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/share/gdm/guest-session/Xsession" pid=610 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  393.262138] type=1400 audit(1306247598.729:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=611 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  393.272282] type=1400 audit(1306247598.741:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=611 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  393.273883] type=1400 audit(1306247598.741:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=611 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  393.389565] type=1400 audit(1306247598.857:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=616 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  393.411543] type=1400 audit(1306247598.877:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=616 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  393.453436] type=1400 audit(1306247598.921:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=613 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  393.506025] Synaptics Touchpad, model: 1, fw: 7.2, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xd04733/0xa40000/0xa0000
[  393.609028] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
[  393.985506] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (064e:c211)
[  394.024541] input: USB 2.0 Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/input/input5
[  394.025683] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  394.025709] USB Video Class driver (v1.0.0)
[  394.882850] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  394.882878] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  394.882906] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  394.882916] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  394.882943] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  394.882970] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  394.882979] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  395.000854] i915 0000:00:02.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[  395.000886] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  395.067278] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.15
[  395.067404] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[  395.067428] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  395.067435] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  395.183370] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
[  395.300262] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[  395.302270] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[  395.302301] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 1 (10.10.2010).
[  395.302308] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[  395.489428] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[  395.491182] [drm] initialized overlay support
[  395.582498] Bluetooth: L2CAP ver 2.15
[  395.582507] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  395.679172] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  395.679181] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  395.742794] Bluetooth: SCO (Voice Link) ver 0.6
[  395.742822] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  395.840388] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x37
[  395.840572] fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[  395.840579] drm: registered panic notifier
[  395.879248] acpi device:01: registered as cooling_device2
[  395.888738] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6
[  395.896534] ACPI: Video Device [IGD0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[  395.902673] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[  396.096476] fixme: max PWM is zero.
[  396.431899] ath9k 0000:07:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[  396.431964] ath9k 0000:07:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  396.498724] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x65
[  396.498752] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[  396.498780] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[  396.498787] ath: Regpair used: 0x65
[  396.498815] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.498844] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.498853] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.498882] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.498908] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.498919] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.498946] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.498974] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.498983] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.499011] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.499037] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.499066] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.499074] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.499102] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.499129] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.499139] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.499166] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.499193] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.499202] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.499230] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.499257] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.499268] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.499294] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2467 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.499322] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.499331] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2472 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[  396.499360] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  396.499386] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz as custom regd has no rule that fits a 20 MHz wide channel
[  396.512544] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain 
[  396.608368] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'ath9k_rate_control'
[  396.629603] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0::radio
[  396.630182] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0::assoc
[  396.633716] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0::tx
[  396.634392] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0::rx
[  396.634453] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9285 Rev:2 mem=0xf8560000, irq=17
[  397.011196] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  397.051152] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
[  397.051404] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[  397.051534] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  397.289225] hda_codec: ALC272: BIOS auto-probing.
[  398.319815] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
[  398.321761] input: HDA Intel Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[  399.041180] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[  399.145577] audit_printk_skb: 9 callbacks suppressed
[  399.145586] type=1400 audit(1306247604.613:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=973 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  399.148806] type=1400 audit(1306247604.617:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=973 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  401.088833] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,commit=600
[  406.550680] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,commit=600
```

Sadly, reinstalling ureadahead has not decreased the time.

Answer (score 2):

Resolving these sort of issues can be more trial and error.  From the look of your trace there is a probably interrupt issue which its hanging on.

So here are a few things to try.

1. Open you BIOS settings.  Try disabling legacy USB Support
2. Try some one of the common boot options - "nomodeset", "noapic", "nolapic" or "acpi=off" as per this [AU question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation/38834#38834).
3. UReadAhead issues - see Rinzwind answer above (you beat me Rinzwind!)
4. Try disconnecting all devices - make sure you limit yourself to having a wired keyboard and mouse plugged in.

You also mentioned that /dev/sda5 was mounting several times.  It might be useful to check that your /etc/fstab file looks ok and that you dont have any cross-mounts.  See mine for an example (n.b. dont copy mine - just see if its as simple as mine)

```
more /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
# Commented out by Dropbox
# UUID=80ff19ee-34d0-484a-9f0d-57ae5fff6caa /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=b309d064-5360-462e-86ff-b380a38bb56a none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=80ff19ee-34d0-484a-9f0d-57ae5fff6caa / ext4 errors=remount-ro,user_xattr 0 1
```

... and confirm that /dev/sda5 isnt cross mounted i.e.

```
mount
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,commit=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/dad/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=dad)
```

Its also worth forcing a filesystem check on reboot

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

Comment: I see what you mean by trial and error! So far I have tried: disconnecting all devices (actually I don't have anything plugged in); disabling the USB Support (no result); fiddling around with UReadAhead (if I remove pack each time before I reboot, then I get down to 3+ minutes instead of 5+ -- not sure this is a permanent solution though; also 3 minutes still seems long). I'm going to try changing the boot options as you said. Could you tell me how I would change the acpi and apic options? My grub2 menu looks just like the AU link you posted and doesn't mention acpi/apic. Thanks!

Comment: @ylam - the example showed where you would add "nomodeset" (at the position of the yellow arrow).  At the same point, try each of the suggested boot options - i.e. press "e" to edit, add "noapic" just before "quiet splash".

Comment: I think we've made progress -- Adding noapic and nolapic as boot options has cut the time down to just under 1 minute! It's not the fastest but I can live with that. I modified the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line to make the change permanent. One doubt remains: the step that takes the longest is still the mounting of sda5. Is it normal that after this happens at around 7 seconds, there's a re-mount of sda5 multiple times afterwards (like 4 other times) during the booting process? What might that mean? Thanks again!

Comment: @ylam - excellent.  Have edited my answer for a few more thoughts.  Dont forget to reinstall ureadahead since this obviously wasnt the issue.

Comment: @fossfreedom sorry this questioned died some time ago and im on a ubuntu FS variant. I wouldnt mind your help! on this topic, have time for a chat?

Comment: @silverpenguin - the Ask Ubuntu chat-room is here (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) feel free to pop in - someone maybe able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I saw some problems with the same a year or so back.

Do you have a file named`/var/lib/ureadahead/pack`?

If so, delete it with `sudo rm /var/lib/ureadahead/pack` and then do a reboot (this will force a rebuild of the pack file used by ureadahead).

After a couple of reboots some have reported to work and some claim the problem came back.

If the latter remove and (re)install ureadahead. You can do that from USC:

[image: im2]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. On just removing pack, the first reboot got me down to about 170 seconds instead of 305. But then the second reboot went back up to 380+ seconds so I used USC to remove and reinstall ureadahead. No luck though -- still have ridiculously long boot time. One thing that I don't know if it's normal is that I've noticed in the boot logs that it's re-mounting sda5 multiple times. I'm going to try to attach my logs from the first and second reboots, if you don't mind taking a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours, I had to edit a udev rule as explained here
http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3116527.0

It is referred also in: 
[Slow boot after clean install of Natty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39316/slow-boot-after-clean-install-of-natty)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should try 'bootchart' to see the time period.
I have the same matter.

```
[    4.271700] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   30.146995] Adding 4988920k swap on /dev/sda8.  Priority:1 extents:1 across:4988920k 
[   30.349896] Adding 4988144k swap on /dev/sdb8.  Priority:1 extents:1 across:4988144k
```

In bootchart, I find ureadahead is working in this period.
You may try :

1. using e4rat.
   http://www.howtogeek.com/69753/how-to-cut-your-linux-pcs-boot-time-in-half-with-e4rat/
2. remove e4rat, and install ureadahead again.