# Boot time over 20 minutes on a virtual server

Tags: 10.04, boot, usb, virtualization

I have a virtual server hosted by professionals with Ubuntu 10.04 installed. It is a standard server installation with LAMP package and no custom modifications.

After recent updates via aptitude boot time of the machine have increased dramatically to over 20 minutes. I noticed that this problem started occurring after updates of linux kernel.

The current version is: `Linux Ubuntu-1004-lucid-64-minimal 2.6.32-32-server`

Judging from the output of `dmesg` it looks like some sort of a problem with USB controller or drivers (dmesg output below). What I don't understand is why it started to happen? And what is the solution/workaround to this problem.

I've found that some people had similar problems and proposed solutions were either disabling USB legacy support in BIOS or upgrading firmware. As I have already mentioned, this machine is a virtual server, so i don't have access to BIOS and hardware.

```
[    0.197693] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.198259] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.198723] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.199237] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: PCI INT D -> Link[LNKD] -> GSI 11 (level, high) -> IRQ 11
[    0.199979] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.199988] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.200470] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.201313] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: irq 11, io base 0x0000c020
[    0.201917] usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[ 1253.897084] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1253.897529] hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[ 1253.897963] PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBD,PNP0f13:MOU] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[ 1253.899106] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[ 1253.899529] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[ 1253.914297] mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[ 1253.915268] rtc_cmos 00:01: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[ 1253.916198] rtc0: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[ 1253.917255] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[ 1253.920528] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
```

#### Update 1

The problem just went away, on 2 separate servers. After several reboots the 20 minute delay no longer occurs. No modifications to the server configuration have been made. I am suspecting that either:

1. Kernel learned itself how to eliminate the delay or
2. Hosting provider changed hardware configuration (improbable due to short time span)

I will keep monitoring boot times and will update the question if it occurs again.

#### Update 2

The problem still exists! It seems to occur only when reboots are **days** aways from each other. Consecutive reboots don't produce this delay.

Adding `noapic` flag to boot parameters **does not help**.

The delay always occurs between the following lines of `dmesg`, with varying duration:

```
[    0.189478] usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[  487.589964] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `nousb` to boot options is a workaround for this problem. It disables the whole USB subsystem during boot, hence, no delay.

I answered (from what you have written) a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44211/very-slow-boot-due-to-mounting-filesytem/44283#44283).

Comment: @fossfreedom Should I set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset noapic"` in the `/etc/default/grub` and then do a `sudo update-grub`? By the way, I just rebooted again and there was no 20 minutes delay and that is without making any changes!

Comment: If you are convinced that one or both of the options is required, then go ahead make the change.  However I'm confused that you said that the issue doesnt occur on a reboot when you have yet to make the change...  Maybe add the options and monitor the situation over a period of time to see if this is the real answer.

Comment: The only thing that I did between reboots is installed `bootchart`, which seems to have modified the boot image somehow. I have another server with previous linux kernel `2.6.32-31-server` and no `bootchart`, rebooting it right now and it already spent 10 minutes doing that. Will run few more tests and report back.

Comment: @dezlov - what virtualisation solution are you using?  If you are using virtualbox - have you tried disabling the USB-Controller in the guest settings?

Comment: I do not host the virtual machine myself, it is hosted by a professional hosting provider. While I was searching for the solution, I came across suggestions to disable USB ports or legacy support (mostly via BIOS), but haven't found a single definitive way of doing this in software on Ubuntu.

Comment: @dezlov - try adding nousb to your grub boot option

Comment: That's the one! `nousb` option is exactly what I needed! Although it is not a solution to the problem, it is a good workaround since I don't need to use USB. Thanks a lot!!