# connection lost Netgear A6200 Usb adapter on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, connection, netgear

I am having the issue with Ubuntu 14.04 with Netgear A6200 wireless Usb adapter. I set up my A6200 Wireless Adapter as described in another thread (https://askubuntu.com/questions/46027...-work-on-14-04) and it works fine for less than a minute. In less than a minute I cant connect to internet anymore. It is still listed as active and connected though. Once i unplug the usb adapter and plug it back in, it connects and again same problem in less than a minute. I would really appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging in a Ethernet cord in to you computer and plug it in to your router then go to settings when you have wired connection. If you don't know what that looks like then where wifi is it should display two arrows pointing at each other. After you hook up ethernet then go into setting and go to software and updates then go to aditinal drivers should be the second to last tab or the last tab then wait until it shows you that there are drivers available and look for your wifi driver and download it and you should have wifi.

Good luck

Comment: This should work if your computer has a wireless card then you won't need the netgear adapter.