# Ureadahead slows down boot process on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ureadahead

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit installed on a WD Velociraptor (10.000 rpm) hard disk. I'm not using Wubi, it's a clear install.

I think that "adding swap" procedure on boot takes too long. At first I thought that it has something to do with the swap mounting, but as you can see, I've spotted the problem in the "ureadahead" deamon.

You can see below `dmesg` partial output:

```
[    5.347709] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 210x65
[    5.351756] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[    5.613411] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   21.421858] Adding 1227772k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1227772k 
[   21.425834] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   21.425841] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
```

[Complete `dmesg` output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1543018/)

Taking into account my hard drive's speed, this delay is not normal.

After upgrading to the latest kernel (3.2.0.36 from 3.2.0.35) or after removing "/var/lib/ureadahead/pack" file, the problem is temporary solved, just for one boot. 
After the second boot the problem returns.

This is the `dmesg` output when everything works perfect:

```
[    5.120096] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 210x65
[    5.124150] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[    5.285586] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    6.953086] Adding 1227772k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1227772k 
[    7.516909] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    7.516916] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
```

[Complete `dmesg` output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1543060/)

As suggested in the comments I've tried to disable the swap mounting and the delay was  moved to the next process, so it seems that **it has nothing to do with swap mounting**:
`dmesg` output:

```
[ 5.862973] EXT4-fs (sda3): recovery complete 
[ 5.887252] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null) 
[ 17.589428] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[ 17.589435] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
```

@gertvdijk noticed that in the latest `dmesg` output my system recovered from something, but this just happened just when I've comment out the swap from "/etc/fstab".

**I've spoted the problem**
Ureadahead slows down the boot process. This is weird since the opposite should happen!
Below I'm posting `bootchart` images and `dmesg` output of three different boots:

1. Without ureadahead (disabled following this [guide](http://ubuntuguide.net/howto-fix-ureadahead-problem-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-10-04)) there is no
   delay:
    
   [dmesg output (ureadahead disabled)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1545633/)
   [bootchart output (ureadahead disabled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScfMm.png)
2. With ureadahead enabled first boot (pack file is build for the first time) no delay:
   [dmesg output (ureadahead enabled)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1545680/)
   [bootchart output (ureadahead disabled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv6KL.png)
3. With ureadahead enabled second boot (ureadahead full working) delay is back:
   [dmesg output (ureadahead enabled second boot)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1545693/)
   [bootchart output (ureadahead disabled second boot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0y81.png)

**NOTE**
My question seems to be a duplicate of this [Very slow boot due to mounting filesytem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44211/very-slow-boot-due-to-mounting-filesytem) which concerns Ubuntu 11.04 and has no solution yet! *If any admin reading this, I don't know if I have to delete my question as a duplicate since the problem doesn't seems to  be the swap mounting... if so, delete it, or please, inform me to do so!*

Comment: Have you tried disabling swap for the time being to exclude all other causes? Just comment (prepend with `#`) the line for swap in `/etc/fstab` and reboot.

Comment: Thank you for your interest!<br/>I've just tried it.. I no more have this issue but again booting takes more time than normal delaying on the next line "ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready"! `dmesg` output:
`[    5.862973] EXT4-fs (sda3): recovery complete
[    5.887252] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   17.589428] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   17.589435] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready`

Comment: Then it's not loading of swap being the cause. I see `recovery complete` in your logs, indicating that you haven't shut down your system properly. I feel there's a lot more going on... like... are you using Wubi for example?

Comment: If you look above the output of the `dmesg` in the first update of my question, 17.589428 is not normal time for ADDRCONF! Sorry for the mess in my comments but how can I add a line break when writing a comment?

Comment: No I'm not using Wubi! It's a clear install!

Comment: Please don't use comments for posting updates. *Edit* your question as being it one question. Also avoid "update #1" at the bottom parts - just make it one piece. We can see the edits you make in the revision history. It's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, you see. :)

Comment: Thank you I'll fix it asap!! I can't find any `recovery complete` in my logs, could you please point me to? Do you know were can I find the shutdown log...?

Comment: You just posted it yourself in [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244450/swap-addition-on-boot-seems-to-take-too-long#comment303520_244450)! (do Ctrl+F on this page if you don't believe me ;))

Comment: :) You are right! I was looking for it in the previous 3 dmesg's outputs, posted in the question above and I could find it...

Comment: It seems you've found a solution (answer) to your issue (question). Can you post it as an answer? Answers don't belong in the question body on this site. Thanks :)

Comment: But it's more like a workaround than a solution... I don't know why my system boots faster without "ureadahead" since more read/writes to HD take place (see first bootchart)! I've just spotted the problem! I'd like to have ureadahead back again because if there is a way to make it work properly, maybe I can get even better performance!

Answer (score 0):

Try e4rat, it's faster and reliable

ppa https://launchpad.net/~trinitronx/+archive/minimal-no-ureadahead

how to use http://www.howtogeek.com/69753/how-to-cut-your-linux-pcs-boot-time-in-half-with-e4rat/

Answer (score 0):

ureadahead is run on the next boot when key packages such as the kernel are updated so that it can determine the location of file data during a boot. If you reboot again after that it should improve the boot speed since it now knows the location of the data and it does not have to re-instrument the files.

Answer (score -1):

Do a clean install of Ubuntu 13.10, it is the latest updated Ubuntu version. Your problems might be fixed under that version, updates always fix problems.