# Slow boot Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, plymouth, dmesg, bootchart

A few months ago I changed on my Lenovo Q180 HTPC from Windows to Ubuntu (only Ubuntu installation, without dual boot). 
Now, after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 I am noticing a slowdown on boot.
Therefore, I followed the instructions to check listing of dmesg.

[dmesg file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7458329/)

I'm not an expert, but I noticed 3 longer gaps in dmesg extract.
The first gap occurs after 4.22 seconds:

```
[    4.220866] random: nonblocking pool is initialized  
[   15.022778] Adding 4188156k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4188156k FS
```

the other after 29.51 seconds:

```
[   29.514165] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready  
[   32.096660] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
```

and third (longer) gap after 32.13 seconds:

```
[   32.133380] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning  
[   55.489238] type=1400 audit(1399922728.858:68): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=2196 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

The sum of these gaps are more than 65% of the boot time displayed by dmesg.
I tried to find answers to these gaps, but unfortunately I could not find nothing, what exactly match my gaps.
I would therefore ask for advice, if there is a way, how to optimize these gaps, or if these gaps are normal.

I am also enclosing bootchart file:
[bootchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1DHC.png)

Lenovo Q180 specifications:
- Intel Atom D2700 @ 2.3GHZ
- 4GB DDR3 RAM
- 320GB Hard Drive (5400 RPM)
- AMD Radeon HD 6450 (512 MB)
- Lenovo N5902 Multimedia Remote with Keyboard
- 10/100/1000 Realtek RTL8111//8168B Gigabit NIC
- 802.11 b/g/n Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless NIC
- 4x USB 2.0 ports(in the back)
- 2x USB 3.0 ports(in the front)
- HDMI and VGA port
- SD/SDHC/SDXC/MMC/MS/MS_Pro card reader

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit the kernel boot parameters, replace `quiet splash` with `debug`, then look at dmesg after booting. You will get a much more detailed boot log.

Comment: Hi Bain, I followed your instructions and attach dmesg file [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7468739/) after modifying kernel (replace quiet splash with debug). Any ideas? Thank you. Erik

Comment: Have you seen [Ureadahead slows down boot process on Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244450/ureadahead-slows-down-boot-process-on-ubuntu-12-04)? You could follow the notes there and see if disabling ureadahead makes any difference. Also see [Ubuntu forums: Ureadahead](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1434502)

Comment: Also see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ureadahead#Helping_out "If your boot actually becomes slower after generating the pack files and you're sure ureadahead is to blame, then file a bug report..."

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but an additional confirmation that a problem do exist. here's mine on Ubuntu 14.04. [ 28.805462] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[ 57.925071] REISERFS (device sdb8): found reiserfs format "3.6" with standard it is a significant 29.119609 seconds additional delay. In Ubuntu 13.04, that same part caused a 10 seconds delay. Something is not right with plymouth.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 computers one with the newer EUFI type BIOS this computer boots just fine with Xubuntu 14.04; However, when I installed it on my older computer with the older BIOS I noticed the computer hung for around 45 seconds before it finally loaded.

I tried several solutions before I found the trick that worked for me. To fix the problem I:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and changed the line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` by putting a # in front of it making it a comment.

After that I ran:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will make the grub menu come up on boot. When I hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to boot the OS from the menu it loaded in about 20 seconds on my machine.