# Boot process idles for 60s doing nothing

Tags: 11.10, boot

My (pretty new) computer boots very slow; I see the purple empty screen for more than a minute until the Ubuntu logo appears.

`dmesg` shows a gap of 60 seconds in which nothing seems to happen (no CPU load or iowait). I suspect is has something to do with `udev` or `udevadm`, since disk utilization spikes when they exit.

I already unplugged everything I could (second harddrive, all usb devices), but that didn't help.

Setting udev logging to "debug" in `/etc/udev/udev.conf` gave me some logs, but without timing information.

What can I do to debug this further?

---

- dmesg: http://tmp.cweiske.de/dmesg-2012-01-09_1442
- bootchart: http://tmp.cweiske.de/sybo-oneiric-20120109-7.png

---

Similar issues:

- [Slow boot after clean install of Natty](https://askubuntu.com/q/39316/15110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I'm hitting [Bug #906358: udev and lvm2 hang at boot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/906358).

I found it when looking at `/var/log/syslog` - the first line in there after the gap was

```
lp: driver loaded but no devices found
```

Searching for it gave me [[xubuntu] Boot hangs for 60 seconds under 3.0.0-14-generic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11587141), which in turn linked to the bug.